# Array is returning undefined

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm currently using this library
[Library](https://github.com/SzymonLisowiec/node-epicgames-client/blob/master/src/Client/index.js)

I've tried printing out the current friends with the eg.GetFriends() function but it returned undefined. I've also tried looping through the GetFriends() and it returned undefined. I've also tried using Json.stringify.

Not sure what the problem is. I've probably approached this the wrong way. Wondering if you guys could help me figure this out.

```
eg.init().then(async (success) => {
try {
    if (success){
        if (await eg.login()) {


              console.log(eg.getFriends())

        }
    }            
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

});

I'm able to sendFriendRequests and invite but i'm unable to retrieve any of the data.

Comment: `getFriends` returns a `Promise`, not `undefined` https://github.com/SzymonLisowiec/node-epicgames-client/blob/master/src/Client/index.js#L293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap all of your logic inside an async function like this:

```
async function retrieveFriends() {

  try {

    const success = await eg.init()

    if (!success) throw 'init failed'

    const loggedIn = await eg.login()

    if (!loggedIn) throw 'login failed'

    const friends = await eg.getFriends()

    return friends

  }

  catch(error) {

    throw error

  }

}
```

...and then you can call it to log the result to the console:

```
retrieveFriends()
  .then(friends => console.log(friends))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it says in the documentation to use it like this

```
async getPendingFriends () {
        let friends = await this.getFriends(true);

        return friends ? friends.filter(friend => friend.status === "PENDING") : [];
    }
```